# What is the possible video format for segmentation and network transfer?

Tags: asp.net, video, video-processing

I have a project on distance education system that I have to segment videos and share it through the network.

My question is that what video format is better to choose? and where can I find some specification details about the video format?

If I divide the video into parts, are they arranged in a sequential order?(ex: the 2nd video frame is exactly located after the first one?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET (and assuming you are running it on IIS), you can utilize [IIS Media Service](http://www.iis.net/media). You can check [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems) for comparision about several delivery platform and formats.

If you split the video properly, then yeah, the first frame of the second video would be relatively (because of predicted frames) after the last frame of the first video.

Answer (score 0):

For the space and bandwidth awesomeness I would start with FLV.

You can get a player here.
http://www.aspnetflashvideo.com/

Answer (score 0):

[WebM](http://www.webmproject.org/) , is a Video codec + file format created created exactly for streaming video over web.It is free(BSD license) code + documentation + standard.

Low computational footprint to enable playback on any device, including low-power netbooks, handhelds, tablets, etc.*

Simple container format

Highest quality real-time video delivery

Click and encode. Minimal codec profiles, sub-options; when possible, let the encoder make the tough choices.